# My weld shop washroom's fan is vented indoors

Tags: bathroom

I work in a weld shop,an employee asked me if the bathroom fan has to be vented outside.right now its just vented out of the bathroom and into the shop.Is there any regulations stating it has to be vented to the outdoors?

Comment: No shower or tub?

Comment: Depends. Where is your weld shop? Also, we're talking commercial building regs here, so kinda off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

If the area is covered by International Building Code, then yes it must be vented outdoors.

> ## International Mechanical Code 2015
>
> ### Chapter 5 Exhaust Systems
>
> #### Section 501 General
>
> **501.3 Exhaust discharge.** The air removed by every mechanical exhaust system shall be discharged outdoors at a point where it will not cause a public nuisance and not less than the distances specified in Section 501.3.1. The air shall be discharged to a location which it cannot again be readily drawn in by a ventilating system. Air shall not be exhausted into an attic, crawl space, or be directed onto walkways.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to have a fan in the bathroom is that you need to be able to draw the humidity out of the room (it also helps with smells, but that's only an upshot). This is mostly caused when you have warm water in the room.

If you're down south, this isn't as big a deal, but up north this can be very problematic. You're dumping warm, moist air into a cold zone with untreated wood. That can promote the growth of mold.

Best practice always is to vent outside (and use insulated line to keep it from condensing within the line)